# Instagram API Sandbox was stopped after login from another place

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Our team is developing web application with Instagram API Sandbox in JAPAN.
But one member tried to login Instagram from HONG KONG (He is there).
After that, the function of API was stopped.

Can anybody help me to fix it?

Detail:
The Security check from Hong Kong is not solved so far.
( After this, he did login again using VPN in JAPAN, and succeeded )

Comment: Maybe you should consult with Instagram directly?

Comment: Thanks. sounds good.